# How to use PHP Array in MySQL Select statement with BETWEEN?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am looking to use the contents of an array

```
$arr =array(24,28,30,34, 40);
```

and pass these into the where clause of a MySQL select statement, all my research has shown this done by using `IN` to pass in all the array values in one go.

I need to pass in each array element one at a time and then echo out the results of the SQL statement one at a time as the select statement is updated with the next array element.

New to programming and PHP so just need a little example to get me started...

Thanks to Zad highlighted the real issue

**I need to pass each array value individually to a SQL statement as these need to be utilised in Where clause with BETWEEN, eg. WHERE age BETWEEN $array1 AND $array2 in order to determine count over an age range**

thanks for all the input

Comment: what code have you got so far?

Comment: So, you need `... WHERE age BETWEEN 24 AND 28`, `... WHERE age BETWEEN 28 AND 30`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the implode function to build the string that contains the list;

```
$arr =array(24,28,30,34, 40);
$query = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (' .implode($arr, ', '). ' )';
echo $query;`
```

http://codepad.org/tLPZxq8P

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: Thanks.. but i need to pass in each element one at a time, I would use IN if i wanted to pass all array elements at once

Comment: Why do you need to pass one by one?, using IN is a lot faster since only requires to query the database once.

Comment: because i want to do a count of the number of records with each loop through

Comment: eg. SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE age = $array

Comment: after using the IN method you can just call the mysql_num_rows function and get the number of records. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE age IN (20, 30, 40 50 ) ?

Comment: but that would give me the number of records for ages 24,28,30,34 and 40 combined...i want the number of records for each individual age group...thanks for your help its really appreciated

Comment: Oh thats easy then just do. SELECT age, COUNT(id) AS total FROM table WHERE age IN (20, 30, 40 50 ) GROUP BY age

Comment: i never thought of just using SQL ..will give it a try.. thanks

Comment: that works but I also need to SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE age BETWEEN 1st$array AND 2nd$array.....SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE age BETWEEN 3rd$array AND 4th$array

Answer (score 1):

try it with escaping the argument

```
foreach($arr as $array_element) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = \''.mysql_real_escape_string($array_element).'\'';
    //your statement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `foreach` function:

```
// make connection to mysql server
foreach ( $arr as $element ) {
    $statement = "SELECT whatever FROM wherever WHERE something = $element"; // maybe a little validation here wouldn't hurt either
    // execute statement
    // process results
} // end of foreach
// close connection
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr =array(24,28,30,34, 40);
$a = 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN('.implode(',',$arr).')';
```

Edit: I'll admit, I didn't fully read the question, the title is misleading - consider changing that.

> I need to pass in each array element one at a time and then echo out
>   the results of the SQL statement one at a time as the select statement
>   is updated with the next array element.

Could you explain how the scenario a bit better?